# Access tasks using Active Directory Azure Library

Tags: android, office365, exchange-server-2010, adal

Developing an android app that needs tasks from outlook.office365.com, where the client's work account is connected with AD, I used ADAL library for authentication and don't find API to access the Tasks. Is there any way to get this done?.Kindly update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found out a way to access the "Tasks" from outlook.office365.com, Please make sure you read the guide here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iqY_tdyJFbVZ2UR0_rGznSvbamDTdm6gNoltfQZghrQ/edit?usp=sharing

It is working, but I had to get the trial license from the developers, still I'm working on the same by using [ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api), once if I find it working, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the API doesn't support interacting with Outlook tasks. You can find all of the Office 365 API documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog).

Comment: Yes, I had already gone through this page, but I couldn't find API for Tasks, that is the issue here.

Comment: Getting Office365.com Tasks on mobile is possible, as an android app named "Tasks & Notes" in the play store fetches Tasks and syncs with server too

Comment: I don't want any third part app, that fetches tasks, I need to implement it in my app.. Pl tell me if there is a way to do this

Comment: You said "Developing an android app that needs tasks from outlook.office365.com". The Outlook API is not able to fetch or create new tasks.

Comment: You should write an answer to your question so other people can use it as a resource. Glad it worked out!